# how to use chrome options in protractor framework?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, protractor

I want to use this code in protractor framework

`setPageLoadStrategy(org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy.NONE);`

`setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:12633");`

Please help me in that.

like

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        "chromeOptions": {
         setExperimentalOption:'debuggerAddress=127.0.0.1:12633'
        }   
      },
```

how can we do like that ??

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: I have edited that. but i think it was the genuine problem I was having..

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. If you want the list of all configurations for protractor check here on official [docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.0/lib/config.ts).

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  pageLoadStrategy :'normal',
  chromeOptions: {
     args: [ "--headless", 
             "--disable-gpu", 
             "--window-size=800,600",
             "--debuggerAddress=127.0.0.1:12633" ]
   }
}
```

You can try like this. But I found that this capability does not present in chrome browser

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'firefox',
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
          'binary': '/opt/bin/firefox',
          'args': ['--verbose'],
          'pageLoadStrategy' :'normal'
      }
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you so much .. but I want to use `setPageLoadStrategy` please tell how can I use that

Comment: @Shyam3 - I have updated answer. Please check it once.

Comment: ohh I just want to do that on chrome only. because I have to automate electron application..If not possible is there any alternative for that option ?

Comment: @Shyam3 - if its a valid capability for chrome then it will work for chrome as written in updated solution

Comment: I have used same in selenium webdriver and there it's working fine. but here in protractor it's not working fine.

But it's not capability, it's chrome option.

like `options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);`